# Javascript double dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a double-dropdown menu using JavaScript & HTML lists. I know there is a lot about it in the internet, but these solutions don't fit me or use jQuery (and I'm doing this for JavaScript practice mostly). I've created something like that:

JS Code:

```
function clear_id() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
}

function dropdown_id(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element.style.display === "block") {
    element.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    clear_id();
    element.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function clear_class(element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; ++i) {
    element[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function dropdown_class(id, num) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
  if (element[num].style.display === "block") {
    element[num].style.display = "none";
  } else {
    clear_class(element);
    element[num].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

CSS Code:

```
ol,
ul {
  display: none;
}

#main {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<ol id="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown_id('first')">First</a>
    <ul id="first">
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="dropdown_class('one',0)">fir</a>
        <ol class="one">
          <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="dropdown_class('one',1)">sec</a>
        <ol class="one">
          <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="dropdown_id('second')">Second</a>
    <ul id="second">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="dropdown_class('two',0)">fir</a>
        <ol class="two">
          <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="dropdown_class('two',1)">sec</a>
        <ol class="two">
          <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

So at this point, I simply have to expand and roll (depending on display state) after click. Here is my solution for that problem.

It works fine, but I feel that it can be done simpler, just don't know JavaScript good enough and I'm blocked by my C++ approach (recently moved from C++ to web because of curiosity). So here is my question: can it be done easier and simpler(maybe more correct)? If anyone can show me the right path, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Question is fine, but you could do us a favor by using the Stack Snippet (button on the editor toolbar looks like `<>`) and put your code in the appropriate boxes (CSS should be without the `<style>` tags, JS without `<script>`). That would let us try it here on SO, not have to navigate to another site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've done it for him :)

Comment: @Archer very kind of you; I like to create opportunities for new folks to learn how to use it on their own :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Now he's seen an example of what can be done I'm sure he has learned.  That's why we're allowed to edit people's questions :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for tip, I'll use it properly next time.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for help!

Comment: @PStarczewski You're welcome, but I think it's all moot anyway.  Your question would actually be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another implementation, I pass in the DOM element using the this keyword which I then use in my javascript function. It is also a bit shorter than your solution but not necessarily better.

```js
function toggle (el) {
  if (el.childNodes[1].className === 'disappear') {
    el.childNodes[1].classList.remove('disappear');
  } else {
    el.childNodes[1].classList.add('disappear');
  }
}
```

```css
.disappear {
  display: none;
}

li:hover{
color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li onclick="toggle(this);">first
        <ul class="disappear">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li onclick="toggle(this);">second
        <ul class="disappear">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Hopefully this is helpful for you!

Comment: That is an interesting approach, I'll try to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I also myself like to see how other people implement things and pick the best solution ;)